# Segmentation fault when trying to access an array inside pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I got segmentation fault when I start running my project.

I have declared 2 different classes

```
Class myfirstclass {
int x[4];
};
```

In the second class

I access the array “x[4]”  using the following

```
myfirstclass  * firstptr;
firstptr -> x[4];
```

Now when I assigned the “firstptr -> x[4];” to an array to do some computations I got a segmentation fault?

```
int y[4];
for (int i=0; i<4;i++){
  y[i]= firstptr -> x[i]; -> "This statement what caused the segmentation fault."
}
```

Can you help me fixing this error, please?

Comment: Did you actually allocate memory for your `firstptr`?

Comment: remove the * and indexes start from 0. i.e. myfirstclass firstptr; firstptr.x[3] is the last element.

Answer (score 1):

If you just do this

```
myfirstclass  * firstptr;
firstptr -> x[4];
```

You haven't initialised `firstptr`. You would need to do something like

```
myfirstclass  * firstptr = new myfirstclass();
```

Don't forget to `delete firstptr` somewhere.

Or just use the stack

```
myfirstclass  first;
```

Next, you are using

```
firstptr -> x[4];
```

Since you have `int x[4];` you have 4 items, so can access `x[0]`, `x[1]`, `x[2]` and `x[3]`. There is no `x[4]`

Note - if you use the stack instead just use `.` instead of `->`

```
first.x[i];
```

Comment: I have missed the point about the allocation and I do it now, but I still got the same segmentation fault on same statement, I mean when I assign this firstptr -> x[i]; to another array in order to do some computation, I got segmentation fault.  y[i]= firstptr -> x[i];

Comment: @redRose why not just use stack variables instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create object before usage. Something like that:

```
myfirstclass  * firstptr = new myfirstclass();
```

Or you should discard using dynamically allocated object

```
myfirstclass  firstptr;
int y[4];
for (int i=0; i<4;i++){
  y[i]= firstptr.x[i]; -> "This statement what caused the segmentation fault."
}
```

In order to access x you should make it public:

```
class myfirstclass {
public:
int x[4];
};
```

Actually, making data field bublic is not recommended.

Comment: @Ivan I have missed the point about the allocation and I do it now, but I still got the same segmentation fault on same statement, I mean when I assign this firstptr -> x[i]; to another array in order to do some computation, I got segmentation fault.  y[i]= firstptr -> x[i];

Comment: @redRose could you show your code (how does it look with fixes)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate your class.

Before the `for` loop do:

```
firstptr = new myfirstclass;
```